# Differential form defined on a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-forms

I've got a question on a statement in do Carmo's "Differential Forms and Applications".
On pages 46/47 he explains what a representation of a differential form $\omega$ on a manifold is. He defines it like this (p. 47): $$\omega_\alpha(v_1,\dots,v_k)=\omega(df_\alpha(v_1),\dots,df_\alpha(v_k)).$$

I don't really understand why this is a reasonable way to define it, because this means the parametrizations $f_\alpha$ are a differentiable maps (from a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ on $M$). But how do I know, that this is always true, because we only have this property in the definiton of regular surfaces (Example 5, p. 43).

Then he claims that the deriviate $d\omega$ defined in the way he explained is unique. But after looking in Spivaks "Integration on manifolds" (p. 117) I figured out that this uses that $df_a$ has to be invertible - how do I know this is true in the abstract setting described by do Carmo?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Remember on overlaps $f_\beta^{-1}\circ f_\alpha$ and $f_\alpha^{-1}\circ f_\beta$ are differentiable, so the derivatives are invertible and all other charts must make $df_\alpha$ invertible when defined, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how can I see that this condition is sufficient for the differentiability of $f_\alpha$
(and that the differential is bijective)?

Comment: I tried to show the diferentiabilty with the definition (p. 38): I would say that you can write:

$$ f_{\beta}^{-1}\circ f_\alpha = f_{\beta}^{-1}\circ f_\alpha \circ Id.$$

Because the first term is differentiable it is the second, that shows that $f_\alpha$ is differentiable. But I don't know how to show that $df_\alpha$ is bijective. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Your question is not complete, but with experience I can try to guess what's going on. $f_\alpha\colon U_\alpha\to\Bbb R^n$ is a chart on an $n$-dimensional manifold $M$. You're asking why $df_\alpha$ is bijective mapping the *tangent space of $M$ at a point* to $\Bbb R^n$? (You keep referring to a regular surface. A manifold is a generalization precisely of this notion.) How did DoCarmo define the tangent space at $p\in M$?

Comment: Dear Mr. Shifrin, it is really cool that you've posted a comment, because I am the one who wrote an email to you years ago from Germany to say thank you for your great youtube videos. And you are the reason why I started thinking about this topic again recently as I worked with your book. 

I got ahead with my question (what I've written above is not correct). Do Carmo doesn't use submanifolfds of $\mathbb{R}^n$, he's working with differential manifolds abtractly. So you have a differential structure and you use the coordinate charts to define differentialbility of a map...

Comment: ...and my question was, how I can use what the first commentator had written to show the differentiability of the map $f_\alpha$. Do Carmo defines the tangent space as the set of all tangent vectors at a point $p$ which are defined as directional derivatives. This is an operator $C^∞(M)\to\mathbb{R}$.